# Auto-play html5 video on center of page in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, html5-video

I am trying to auto-play a video on web page when the video element is at the center of the screen. It works just fine in Firefox and IE. But works in Chrome only when I am using arrow keys to scroll down.

If I use mouse for scrolling, the event fires but video never plays. What could be wrong here?

Following is my html code for the video:

```
<video id="video1">
    <source src="~/Videos/maintenance.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="~/Videos/maintenance.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <img src="~/Images/home_maintenance.png" title="No video playback capabilities" />
</video>
```

And the jquery code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Get media
        var media = $('#video1');

        function checkMedia() {
            // Get current browser top and bottom
            var tolerance = 300;
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop() + tolerance;

            media.each(function (index, el) {
                var yTopMedia = $(this).offset().top;
                var yBottomMedia = $(this).height() + yTopMedia;

                if (scrollTop > yTopMedia) {
                    $(document).unbind('scroll');
                    console.log(el);
                    $(el).get(0).play();
                } 
            });
        }
        $(document).on('scroll', checkMedia);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you using the each loop for one media with id `#video1`?, and seems like a lot of work for the browser to execute that function on every scroll.

Comment: @SergioAlen This is just a simplified version of code. Real code is lot more complex and does need this functionality.

Comment: Why `$(document).unbind('scroll');`?

Comment: @Novice because I only want to run it once.